# Android is freezing background Service. Volley using loop to send GET request

Tags: android, android-studio

First of all, I am not an Android developer and this is the first time I am successfully building an android package and using Android Studio. I built the code watching some youtube videos for a couple of hours and got bootstrap codes from ChatGPT.

The app uses Volley library to send a GET request to a remote endpoint which returns a JSON string. It then reads the content, retrieves value of a parameter which is of a text. Then it is sending the text to my number.

The code works - except, android is freezing the app after certain minutes, around 30 minutes. This is random, sometimes it runs as long as an hour.

Here are the relevant parts of the code

```
public class SMSService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "SMSServiceBackground";
    private static final long INTERVAL_MS = 30000; // Query interval in milliseconds (e.g., 1 minute)
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        private RequestQueue requestQueue;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "Querying");
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                        Request.Method.GET,
                        "https://mywebsite.com/endpoint",
                        null,
                        response -> {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("body");
                                Log.e(TAG, "Received " + jsonArray.length());
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String smsBody = item.getString("text");
                                    sendSMS(smsBody);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "JSON exception received " + e.getMessage());
                                //e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        },
                        error -> {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                );

                jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);// no caching url...
                jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(
                        new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                10000,//time to wait for it in this case 20s
                                20,//tries in case of error
                                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
                        )
                );
                if( this.requestQueue == null ){
                    File cacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "Volley");
                    this.requestQueue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()), 4);
                    requestQueue.start();
                }
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + exception.getMessage());
            }
            // Reschedule the task
            handler.postDelayed(this, INTERVAL_MS);
        }
    };
   }
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String smsBody) {

// Send using :             smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

}
}
```

I am also starting this service from `MainActivity` using `startService(new Intent(this, SMSService.class));`

I do not see any useful information on logcat.

I've the following permissions assigned.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

I am seeing the app is running in the background because of `START_STICKY` so I don't believe this is a question of whether the app is running in the background or not, however, it is not sending the HTTP requests after a few minutes (around 20-40 minutes time). Any clue what would be the issue or where to look for some clues?

Comment: You schedule a request every 30 seconds but your retry policy (10s and 20 attempts) may far exceed the schedule rate accumulating many requests - doesn't explain much but perhaps in your run method check the last request has completed before launching another.  You can override the `retry` for further diagnostics.  Btw, the default backoff implementation grows the timeout by one interval.

Comment: I added those lines very recently as part of troubleshooting. Merely a copy/paste from some place I'd admit. So are you suggesting that it could be crashing or freezing because the remote server isn't responding in a timely manner causing the retry policy to trigger? I didn't quite understand what you meant by the backoff implementation. Would it help if I remove that policy so the default policy applies?  Also, how can I change this to run only one instance at a time and synchrony? Sorry if I am asking wrong questions as I am completely new here.

Comment: I adjusted it to 5 seconds timeout and 2 retries. Now instead of every 20-30 minutes, the script is running longer but still freezes.

Comment: I am invoking the service from `MainActivity`   `startService(new Intent(this, SMSService.class));`   Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of this restriction. So it looks like I may need to rewrite this using `JobScheduler` to make it work the way that I want.

Comment: Agreed - that is what I get out of the documentation as well - or Foreground Service - if you haven't already, I'd start [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) .

Comment: @Computable I rewrote it using `WorkManager` based on a few examples I've found online. Aparently `WorkManager` is better than `JobScheduler`. Here is the code snippet [Code](https://gist.github.com/zerowebcorp/3dc48107529cdef83be1c02e3f96ef35) Android is also stopping this job after a few minutes. I do not see any reason in the logcat why this is being stopped.

Comment: Ran your code snippet on an API 33 emulator, put app in bg and its been running for ~14 minutes "Checking for queue" message...For grins turned on battery saver mode with no effect.  Do you have a specific API targeted?  Used emulator controls to set battery level to 10% - and voila app stopped.

Comment: I was running the app on an actual physical device as I don't know how to test the SMS sending capability in a simulator. The device had over 80% charge all the time which I made sure of it. It is a S22 Ultra Galaxy device. Weird thing is that if I see the app running in the background if I goto the task manager in the phone and I have a "Force Stop" button available, however the process inside the app appears to be frozen with no explanation. Happy to show you real code if there is a way for us to contact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254683/discussion-between-zeroweb-and-computable).

Answer (score 0):

A normal Service (1) shares same UiThread/MainThread of Main App and could freeze the Interface while waiting for completion, (2) is created for SHORT operations and not for long tak running in background (a ForegroundService exists for that purpose) because Android (Doze) could kill or freeze an App/Service at any time.

Comment: What is a solution for the longer running task.?

Comment: IntentService (but you need to sync Ui updates), AsyncTask (deprecated now), manual "new Thread()" and all the stuff that allow you to execute it on a different Thread.

Comment: Android, especially on Samsung builds, kills all those

Comment: I'm developing SPen (the Samsung Stylus in hardware) Apps and a ForegroundService (based on an IntentService) is not killed by Samsung OS or a 3rd party MediaPlayer, for example, would be killed while playing and it's unbelievable. So: there are methods for "infinite" running tasks....